# React useEffect caused infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http-post, use-effect

I searched lots of post about infinite loop when using useEffect, but still can't figure it out

Inside the useEffect, I was trying to call get accounts api, and of course, I put an empty array because I only want it run once after render. But currently I like to add 'addAccount' function. So, if I press the add button, then it sends a post request. Here is the question, I would like to check if the value has changed or not, so I put the value into the second parameter which is the empty array, and it causes infinite loop. However, if I keep the empty array, my screen does not re-render.

```
export default function BC() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState([])

  async function getBCAccount() {
    const result = await axios.get("http://localhost:3004/accounts")
    if(result) {
      setValue(result.data)
    }
  }
  
  async function createBCAccount() {
    const result = await axios.post("http://localhost:3004/accounts", {
      id: 5,
      name: "mmm"
    })
  }
  
  useEffect(()=> {
    getBCAccount()
  }, [])

  const handleAddAccount = () => {
    createBCAccount()
  }

  return (
    <BcContainer>
      <button onClick={handleAddAccount}>add</button>
      {value && value.map((v)=> (
        <AccountContainer key={v.id} to={`/bc/${v.id}`}>
          <p>{v.name}</p>
          <p>{v.coin} BTC</p>
        </AccountContainer>
      ))}
    </BcContainer>
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just call `getBCAccount` inside `createBCAccount`. After `create`, you will call `get` data again to update your `value`:

```
  async function createBCAccount() {
    await axios.post("http://localhost:3004/accounts", {
      id: 5,
      name: "mmm"
    })
    getBCAccount()
  }
```

Comment: You don't even need to necessarily call `getBCAccount()`, since it will make another `get` call to the endpoint. Since the `post` request already returns a result containing all the accounts, I'd just call `setValue` on that result.

Comment: Are you sure `post already returns a result containing all the accounts,`?

Comment: The result of post request doesn't contain all accounts, only the posted data. And, why can't I detect the value change inside the second parameter of useEffect. So, if value changes, then re-render. Or, there is something I misunderstand how useEffect works.

Comment: Ah my bad, I assumed incorrectly.

Effects will run after the render cycle completes with the new data for the value variable (after the setValue is called with the new result). The way your component works, it doesn't make sense to synchronize (re-run the effect) based on the value variable changing since the `post` does not depend on it.

Based on what you're saying, Viet's answer seems reasonable to me, I'd go with that. I'd probably rename the get to something like `refreshAccounts` or something, but that's stylistic.