# React does not re-render component after state update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

I am writing a React page that displays a list of quizzes that is being fetched by an external API. At the same time, my page has a "New Quiz" button which opens up a dialog with a form for the user to configure and create a new quiz.

Here is the issue: I am not sure how I can make my table re-render once the POST request is completed. After playing around with the 2nd argument of useEffect() for a bit, I am ultimately faced with 2 scenarios:

1. Table re-renders after POST, but useEffect goes into infinite loop
2. useEffect does not go into infinite loop, but table does not re-render

Here is my code:

```
   const handleSubmit = () => {
    setLoading(true);

    const body = {
      name: newQuizName,
      collectionId: newQuizCollection,
      length: newQuizLength,
      estimator: newQuizEstimator,
      survey: newQuizSurvey
    }

    axios.post(quizzes_api, body).then(res => console.log(res));
    fetchQuizzes();
    resetDialog();

    setLoading(false);
   }

   const quizzes_api = `http://localhost:5000/quizzes`;
   const pools_api = `http://localhost:5000/pools`;

   const fetchQuizzes = () => {
     axios.get(quizzes_api).then(res => setQuizzes(res.data));
   }

   const fetchPools = () => {
     axios.get(pools_api).then(res => setPools(res.data))
   }

   useEffect(() => {
     fetchQuizzes();
     fetchPools();
   }, [])
```

Since the 2nd argument used here is [], it is the version that does not re-render. I have tried putting [quizzes], which solves the issue on the front-end; but my flask server gets flooded with GET requests.

I will also note that this is very similar to the question in this thread: [React useEffect caused infinite loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69038890/react-useeffect-caused-infinite-loop)

However, I am not able to solve the problem with the solution offered over there.

Any insights will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  const handleSubmit = () => {
    setLoading(true);

    const body = {
      name: newQuizName,
      collectionId: newQuizCollection,
      length: newQuizLength,
      estimator: newQuizEstimator,
      survey: newQuizSurvey
    }

    axios.post(quizzes_api, body).then(res => console.log(res));
    fetchQuizzes();
    resetDialog();

    setLoading(false);
   }
```

here you're fetching before the post request is completed hence you're not getting an updated results. use `async await` and run `fetchQuizzes` only after the post is completed.

Also, `useEffect` runs whenever anything changes in the dependency array...so if you change some dependency from inside the `useEffect`, it'll cause an infinite loop

Comment: thank you so much for your response. indeed, adding async/await onto the handleSubmit() handler has resolved the issue.

Comment: why not provide the solution instead of just describing it, e.g. add a code snippet showing how to use `async/await`?

Comment: @thedude the guy solved it as mentioned by him in the reply...sometimes people just need a hint..

Comment: sure, but what about the next guy that comes along?

Comment: no worries guys, i have added a short snippet on the original post for future readers :-)